# Django Static files not found

Tags: python, css, django

I am working on a website which uses Django framework. I have put my project related static files in the folder called `our_static` and `collectstatic` files in `static`. Below are my settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "our_static"), 
]
```

base.html file:

```
{% load staticfiles %}    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}" />
</head>
```

Here `our_static` files are not at all getting read. My `style.css` is in `our_static` folder.

EDIT:
I am using AWS EC2 ubuntu 14.04 as my server, the website is working fine in localhost but not in AWS ubuntu server. I am using the Apache2 server.

More config:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATICFILES_FINDERS =[
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
```

my Apache2 config:

```
Alias /static /home/ubuntu/pythonserver/static
<Directory /home/ubuntu/pythonserver/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/ubuntu/pythonserver/pythonserver>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess pythonserver python-path=/home/ubuntu/pythonserver python-home=/home/ubuntu/knowmenow/
WSGIProcessGroup pythonserver
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/pythonserver/pythonserver/wsgi.py
```

Comment: is this on local or a server? Please add your `BASE_DIR` setting. If on a server what is your corresponding config? In either case, what is this showing up as in your rendered html? `href="{% static 'style.css' %}"`?

Comment: In local server it is working fine, problem comes when I deploy to aws server(ubuntu). `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
` is my `BASE_DIR`.

Comment: What webserver are you using (e.g., NGINX, Apache?) - please provide the config. What does `href="{% static 'style.css' %}"` show up as in the html in your browser when you inspect the site's rendered html?

Comment: What is your `STATICFILES_FINDERS` setting? Make sure you're providing all config otherwise it's hard to answer this question

Comment: I am using apache2. When I inspect the web browser it is showing not found error in the browser console. `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://xxxxxxxxxx/static/style.css`.

Comment: My `STATICFILES_FINDERS =[
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
`

Comment: Try removing the trailing slash here: `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")` - otherwise the issue is in your Apache config and you'd need to provide that.

Comment: Will you please please let me know what configuration do you need about apache2? I am new to apache setup

Comment: Your `httpd.conf` or `httpd-vhosts.conf` files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in your Apache configuration - probably in your `httpd.conf` file. Take a look at any tutorial like https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-centos-7#configure-apache which will explain how to set this up. An example `httpd.conf` file would look like the following if you're using `mod_wsgi`:

```
Alias /static /home/user/myproject/static
<Directory /home/user/myproject/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/user/myproject/myproject>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/user/myproject:/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup myproject
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
```

You should also inspect the output of your Apache error logs, which will help debug. They're usually at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: I edited my question with configuration please check

Comment: Thank you I figured out the problem. Problem is in the conf as you said. I need to set the static files directory here in this file like you said. when I change the `static` to `our_static` it is loading the files. Is there any way that I need to load two directories static and our_static in httpd.conf file rather than just one directory?

Comment: Hmmmmmmm are you running `collectstatic` on production? Sounds like that may be your issue if the files are available at `our_static` but not `static`. You shouldn't have to put `our_static` in your apache config. Check whether the `static` directory is populated on your server. Are `our_static` and `static` directories in the same place/at the same level in your directory structure?

Comment: I did not run `collectstatic` in production. I have just deployed static folder from local server to aws server along with my code. admin files are loading anyhow. static directory is there in the server.

Comment: `static` and `our_static` are in same directory.

Comment: `our_static` contains files I wrote and `static` contains admin static files from 'collectstatic'. I just ran the collectstatic in production after removing old copied static files. But the problem is there. Need to figure out how to include bothe static directories in apache configuration file

Comment: Or else I have to just  have to move a directory into another one to use which is not a good way

Comment: Make sure ownership and permissions of the `static` and `our_static` folders are the same. Same with the contents. If they are the same then there should be no reason you can't use the `static` directory, which should contain all files from `our_static` plus any other static files from other locations after you run `collectstatic`. You may have to make sure your Django user has permission to create the proper type of folder that is accessible to your apache server before you run `collectstatic`.

Comment: I dont know what happened I just put it back as before in confguration file and thaought of working on later.. I ran server again.. it is working now...

Comment: @Naroju probably you just needed to run collectstatic :P